# map leaflet polyline Unable to connect across the Pacific

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

now

[image]

i want
[image]

i want to polyline can  connect across the Pacific

what do i need to do

```
L.polylineDecorator(
        data,
        {
            patterns: [
                { offset: 0, repeat: 10, symbol: L.Symbol.dash({pixelSize: 5, pathOptions: {color: '#000', weight: 1}}) },
                { offset: '16%', repeat: '33%', symbol: L.Symbol.marker({rotate: true, markerOptions: {
                    icon: L.icon({
                        iconUrl: 'icon_plane.png',
                        iconAnchor: [16, 16]
                    })
                }})}
            ]
        }
    ).addTo(map);
```